# Generar matriz en Python desde un fichero CSV donde hacer búsquedas mostrando fila encontrada

Tags: python, array, csv, matrices

Tengo un fichero CSV, delimitado por comas, con datos de prueba:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
  CID  ,categoria,edad, Alias   ,Nombre,Provincia
#-----------------------------------------------
     0 ,suave    ,18  ,@depende1,José  ,Alicante 
  3282 ,basto    ,27  ,@Basto27 ,Ramon ,Madrid   
  2015 ,mustio   ,35  ,@mustio35,Luis  ,Huelva   
     0 ,elegante ,22  ,@Dosydos ,Xavi  ,Valencia
```

Necesito leer el fichero y construir una matriz. A partir de ésta, al seleccionar una columna, se mostraran todos sus elementos y al seleccionar uno de ellos deberá mostrarse toda la fila. Por ejemplo, seleccionando *'Alias'* y luego *'@Dosydos'*, se mostrarían todos los campos de esa fila.

Soy nuevo en **Python** y llevo días haciendo pruebas sin éxito.

Por ahora he conseguido crear la matriz a partir del csv, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
import csv
fichero = 'fichero.csv'
results = []
with open(fichero) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    for lista in reader: # Cada fila es una lista
        results.append(lista)
print(results [4][5])
print(results [4])
```

Comment: Hola Ramón, ¿tiene que ser con Python estándar?¿Puedes usar Pandas? Si has encontrado la solución es mejor que lo agregues como una respuesta, explicandolo. Un saludo.

Comment: No tiene que ser estandard. He probado numpi y pandas, pero sin exito. Estoy probando cosas y cuando termine lo daré como respuesta. De momento solo he conseguido manejar la matriz y eso es un gran paso

Comment: Ramon ¿Quieres acceder por nombre de columna y luego dentro de esta columna que busque el elemento que tu quieras? Por ejemplo, si ingresas 'Alias' y  '@Dosydos' literalmente te retorne la fila correspondiente, en vez de tener que usar indices manualmente como haces por ahora. Si buscas algo así Pandas, te puedo dejar un ejemplo simple si es esto lo que quieres.

Comment: Si que te lo agradecería

Comment: Ramón he creado una respuesta, cualquier duda comentado.  Es una selección simple, se puede hacer búsquedas mucho más complejas si las necesitas. Me he basado en tu csv literalmente, incluyendo las lineas con comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que pretendes seleccionar y filtrar dados usar Pandas es una solución muy simple ya que estas son operaciones básicas de la librería.

Para seleccionar la fila (o filas si hay varias) que contengan '@Dosydos' en la columna "Alias" (o cualquier otra combinación) basta con usar `pandas.read_csv` para cargar el csv en un `DataFrame` y luego aplicar una máscara boleana:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("fichero.csv",  sep=',',  comment='#')
res = df[df["Alias"] == "@Dosydos"] 
print(res)
```

**Salida:**

```
   CID categoria  edad     Alias Nombre  Provincia
3    0  elegante    22  @Dosydos   Xavi  Valencia
```

Esto nos crea otro DataFrame que solo contiene las filas que tienen "@Dosydos" en la columna "Alias". Vamos por partes:

- **`df["Alias"]`** selecciona la columna con el header "Alias".
- **`df["Alias"] == "@Dosydos"`** crea una mascara boleana, es una serie boleana que por cada fila tiene False si no contiene "@Dosydos" y True si lo tiene:

  ```
  >>> df["Alias"] == "@Dosydos"

  0    False
  1    False
  2    False
  3     True
  Name: Alias, dtype: bool
  ```
- Con **`df[df["Alias"] == "@Dosydos"]`** hacemos un indexado del DataFrame `df` usando el "array" boleano anterior. En este caso solo la fila  4 es seleccionada. Si existieran más filas que cumplan la condición serian incluidas también, manteniendo el orden.

Si queremos convertir el dataframe res en una lista o un array de NumPy no hay problema, aunque mejor trabajar en todo momento con Pandas/NumPy por cuestiones de eficiencia:

```
>>> array = res.values
>>> array
array([[0, 'elegante', 22, '@Dosydos', 'Xavi', 'Valencia ']], dtype=object)

>>> lista = res.values.tolist()
>>> lista
[[0, 'elegante', 22, '@Dosydos', 'Xavi', 'Valencia ']]
```

De esto se deduce que esta es una forma simple de crear un array de NumPy a partir de un CSV:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> matriz = pd.read_csv("fichero.csv",  sep=',',  comment='#').values
>>> matriz

array([[0,       'suave', 18, '@depende1', 'José', 'Alicante '],
       [3282,    'basto', 27, '@Basto27', 'Ramon', 'Madrid   '],
       [2015,   'mustio', 35, '@mustio35', 'Luis', 'Huelva   '],
       [0,    'elegante', 22, '@Dosydos',  'Xavi', 'Valencia ']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: ¡Impresionante! , muchas gracias. (ya me dirás que te debo)